# Suppress page break in mindflow environment

Tags: page-breaking, mindflow

The `mindflow` environment provided by the package "mindflow" wraps text in two wide lines `\mfSepLine`, which is defined by

```
\newcommand*{\mfSepLine}{%
  \parskip=0pt
  \LNturnsONfalse%
  \ifLineNumbers\LNturnsONtrue\fi\nolinenumbers%
  \par\noindent\nopagebreak%
  \if@mindflow@incolumn%
    \makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\linewidth}{\mindflowLineHeight}}%
  \else%
    \hspace*{-\paperwidth}%
    \makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{4\paperwidth}{\mindflowLineHeight}}%
  \fi%
  \nopagebreak\par%
  \ifLNturnsON\linenumbers\fi%
}
```

However, even with two `\nopagebreak`s before and after the line, sometimes the separation line is still located on a new page. Below is an example when the second separation line is on the next page alone:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{mindflow}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext[5]
\begin{mindflow}
    \blindtext
    More text
    % \nopagebreak
\end{mindflow}

\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

How should I fix this behavior?

By the way, is it possible to make sure that there are at least two lines of text with this separation line when it is near the page break?

Comment: I edited my answer below due to a mistake I didn't notice. And I have simplified the code.

Comment: @Ivan Would you mind having a look at this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/598440/194994? BTW, I didn't place `\break` and `\nowidow` in the same place of yours (I inserted them in `\mfSepLine` instead of `\endmindflow`), so if there's any error then the fault is on me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add two `\nobreak` and one `\widowpenalty10000` in the `mindflow` environment. At least, this is my attempt to solve the problem.
You can redefine the environment directly:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\endmindflow}{%
  \widowpenalty10000%<---MODIFIED
  \par\nobreak%<---MODIFIED
    \vspace{-.5\baselineskip}\color{mindflowLine}\nobreak\mfSepLine%<---MODIFIED
    \ifLNturnsON\linenumbers\fi%
    \setcounter{mfLN}{\value{linenumber}}%
    \setcounter{linenumber}{\value{recordLN}}%
}
\makeatother
```

or using `etoolbox`, like in the following MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{mindflow}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\endmindflow}
  {\par\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}\color{mindflowLine}\mfSepLine}
  {\widowpenalty10000
    \par\nobreak\vspace{-.5\baselineskip}\color{mindflowLine}\nobreak\mfSepLine}
  {}
  {}

\begin{document}

\blindtext[5]
\begin{mindflow}
\blindtext
    More text%
\end{mindflow}

\end{document}
```

If you prefer, you can load the `nowidow` package and replace `\widowpenalty10000` with `\nowidow[2]`. The advantage is that if you want to keep three lines together instead of two it will be enough: `\nowidow[3]`.

[image]